# Remmina against a specific port and display

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

I run x11vnc in my office. It's running on display :1 and a nonstandard port dictated by the firewall.

Usually I use xtightvncviewer against it, but I thought I would try remmina. When I run remmina I get a form that lets me pick vnc plugin, and a server. I don't see any place for the display number or port number.

How do I specify it.

Comment: Are you even running an supported version of Ubuntu? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tool tip for add connection]

As shown in the tool tip when you hover over the Server field, `server:port`, e.g. `192.168.1.1:5901` is the correct format.

This is also the common way of giving a port number; a colon after the server IP or name.

Comment: Thanks, that worked easily. Now another question. Is there some way to scale the image down by maybe 10% so that the whole remote desktop can be displayed at once? Failing that is their some way to scroll vertically, I only see a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Ask a new question.